# Seeing if conditional formatting of two cells are highlighted excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way to see if two cells are both highlighted under conditional formatting. I've been searching online but can't find anything.

my spread sheet looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ALan.png). For example K75 is highlighted while %75 is not. I would like T75 to have a number 0 for not a match and 1 for a match.

I think the IF function would come into play here and would be something like...

```
=If(K75=S75,1,0)
```

but this is only good for numbers.

If anyone knows how to see if cells are both highlighted through a function it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reproduce the conditions of the CFR(s) to achieve the result. Why don't you think that comparing two text strings is any different than comparing two numbers?

Comment: You can check if a cell has been 'highlighted' in a sub procedure with the .DisplayFormat property but you cannot use the .DisplayFormat in a UDF.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped

Answer (score 0):

Filter both columns by colour (assuming you have that functionality) and insert `1`s in ColumnT. Then filter out the `1`s from ColumnT and insert `0`s.